# Is there an update all command for xcodebuild command line for a svn project?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, svn, xcodebuild

Is there an update all command for xcodebuild command line for a svn project?

I am able to perform clean build and install and launch the app.
Is there a Xcode command line buildaction to perform update all so as to get the latest changes made in the source code, updated in my local workspace from svn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Your project from command line and type below command

```
svn update
```

this command will fetch all the changes done on svn server repository.

Answer (score 1):

You should check command list using command `svn help`.

Run command `svn help` in your terminal (mac app) and see available list of commands (Command list/code depends upon, type of **SVN** you've installed in your system. In general cases, all types of SVN has same commands but its better to check, available commands for your SVN)

If you've installed [<kbd>Apache - Subversion</kbd>](http://subversion.apache.org/), then here are all available commands for it.

[image]

To update your svn files: Run command: `svn update` or `svn up`

[image]